# Prove an inequality in real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, substitution

Prove that the inequality below holds for all the real numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, such that $1>z>0$:

$(2+z)*(∣x+y+yz∣+∣x+y−yz∣)≥2*z*(|x|+|y|)$

My approach is to consider 8 cases (1 case for $a,b>0$, 3 cases for $a>0$ and $b<0$, etc.). Is there any shorter way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=0$ so we need to prove that $2(2+z)|x|\geq2z|x|$, which is obvious.

Let $y\neq0$ and $\frac{x}{y}=a$. Hence, we need to prove that:
$$(2+z)\left(|z+1+a|+|z-1-a|\right)\geq2z\left(1+|a|\right)$$
If $a\geq0$ so $-1-a\leq z\leq1+a$, which says that we need to prove
$$(2+z)(z+1+a-z+1+a)\geq2z(1+a)$$ or 
$$2+z\geq z$$
If $a\leq0$ so we'll replace $a$ on $-a$ and we need to prove that
$$(2+z)\left(|z+1-a|+|z-1+a|\right)\geq2z\left(1+a\right)$$
for $a\geq0$.

Consider two cases.

1. $0\leq a\leq1$.

Hence, $(2+z)\left(|z+1-a|+|z-1+a|\right)\geq(2+z)\left(z+1-a+z-1+a\right)=$

$=2(2+z)z\geq2z\left(1+a\right)$

2. $a\geq1$.

a) $0<z\leq a-1$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$(2+z)\left(-(z+1-a)+z-1+a\right)\geq2z\left(1+a\right)$$ or
$$2(2+z)(1+a)\geq2z(1+a)$$
which is obvious.

b)$z\geq a-1$.

In this case we need to prove that
$$(2+z)\left(z+1-a+z-1+a\right)\geq2z\left(1+a\right)$$ or
$$2(2+z)z\geq2z(1+a)$$ or
$$2+z\geq1+a$$
which is just our case.

Done!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really helpful, but I don't understand how did you get the inquality $(2+z)(|z+1+a|+|z−1−a|)≥2z(1+|a|)$? If you've divided both sides of the inequality from the problem by $y$, didn't you have to assume $y=|y|$, which means $y≥0$?

Comment: @DavSwint I divided a both sides by $|y|$.